# Suspend frame, run a bash command, sleep for a few seconds and come back to emacs

Tags: frames, bash, suspend

[ I'm using the latest emacs, and always emacsclient with the -nw option in a terminal ]

I have this workflow I want to "automate" with an emacs hotkey. I find myself doing this over a hundred times a day:

```
C-z # or M-x suspend-frame to minimize/bg emacs)
# now I'm at bash prompt
$ /usr/local/bin/t   # this runs some bash tests I wrote
$ sleep 5 # I stare at the test results for about 5 seconds
$ fg   # I resume my work in emacs
```

Comment: Why don't you use `M-x shell`  or `M-x eshell`?

Comment: And your command could also be run via `M-x shell-command` in the background, showing the result at end either in minibuffer or a new buffer, depending on output size.

Comment: `(suspend-emacs "/usr/local/bin/t && sleep 5 && fg")`?

Answer (score 1):

As xuchunyang nearly pointed out, you can write those lines in your `~/emacs.d/init.el`

```
(defun suspend-and-run ()
    (interactive)
    (suspend-emacs "/usr/local/bin/t && sleep 5 && fg"))

(global-set-key (kbd "<f5>") 'suspend-and-run)
```

then when pressing `F5` your stuff will be executed.

If you replace `sleep 5` with `read` then you can look at the output until you press return.

This all works only with terminal-emacs, X11-emacs will refuse to do this.

Comment: Shouldn't we use `suspend-frame` in case we are using emacs daemon?

Comment: It gives following error: `Wrong number of arguments: (0 . 0), 1`