# Wrong number of arguments: (0 . 0), 1 error on suspend-emacs and run command in shell

Tags: terminal-emacs, suspend

I am trying to `suspend-frame` and run command: `clear` in the shell in order to hide warning message: `[3]  + 31360 suspended (signal)  TERM=xterm-256color emacsclient -t -q ~/.emacs`

I have add this script from this answer (https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/33449/18414):

```
(defun suspend-and-clear ()
   (interactive)
   (suspend-frame "clear"))

(global-set-key "\C-]" 'suspend-and-clear);
```

This gives me following error: `Wrong number of arguments: (0 . 0), 1`. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK in a terminal you genuinely are *suspending the process*.  So Emacs can't *do* anything after that -- it was a foreground process, and it has been stopped.

However, it's `suspend-tty` which is ultimately called (see which), and that runs an abnormal hook `suspend-tty-functions`.  The functions are run with one argument, the terminal object to be suspended.  So if you can establish a way to clear the terminal based on that value, you might be able to achieve what you want.

Note that the message you are wanting to hide is a job control message; and while I can't remember if it's the shell or the tty/OS which generates it, either way it won't be generated until *after* Emacs has been stopped, which means whatever you were going to do via that hook (i.e. while Emacs is running) would need to take delayed effect.

Comment: I will investigate it,  at least if I can redirect its output as `2> /dev/null` would help me to achieve that I want as well

Comment: I was not able to manage to supress `suspend-emacs` output on the terminal. Is it possible to accomplish it? @phils

Comment: I don't really know, sorry.  My guess is "probably", but it feels like a very fiddly thing to accomplish, and I'm afraid I'm not inspired to try to figure it out myself.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I do suspend and afterwards continue a lot, sometimes seeing all the `signal suspend` stuff seems unnessary but i will get used to it.

Comment: I also believe this issue is beyond `emacs`, where should be handled by kernel level to supress signal messages.

Answer (score 1):

`suspend-frame` doesn't take any arguments, which is why you're getting that error message. Call `suspend-emacs` instead.

Comment: I also tried that but `suspend-emacs` does not do anything, I am using it via `emacs-daemon`.

Comment: Then what you want isn't possible.

Comment: So I cannot use `suspend-emacs` on a session of emac daemon and I don't have any alternative solution for this