# Is it possible to disable suspend output when Ctrl-z pressed in Emacs?

Tags: suspend

When I suspend `emacs` (clicking `ctrl-z`) I get following output on the terminal:

`[4]  + 7317 suspended  emacs -nw -q file.py`, I was wondering is it possible to prevent this output to printed.

I tried `stty susp undef` but it didn't help.

[@disabling job control in bash (CTRL-Z)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137915/disabling-job-control-in-bash-ctrl-z/137924#137924) mentions emacs should be reconfigured individually for this.

> `stty susp undef` will disable the keyboard-initiated suspend signal
> for most programs, however commands like vim and `emacs` that have
> specific bindings for `Ctrl-Z` will have to be reconfigured
> individually.

---

Also I set `set +m` as advices in this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/137917/198423), after pressing `CTRL+z` inside emacs, shell gets frozen and I cannot close it even using `CTRL+c`

Comment: The message is not printed by emacs, so emacs cannot do anything about it.

Comment: Running `set +m` prevent message to be printed out but emacs couldnt complete to suspend operation and I think freeze on the console

Comment: Isn't that because job control is then disabled?  Which also has nothing to do with emacs.

Comment: Yes I think so. For exaple do this `timeout 5s sleep 5 2>&1 &` you will see the `[N] ..` outputs. Than do `set +m` and re-do it you won't see. I apply same thing for emacs but when I suspend emacs, shell get hang. I think its better if I ask it on unix.stack

Comment: Cross-referencing with https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/58446/454

Answer (score 1):

You cannot disable this message by configuring Emacs because it comes from your shell, not from Emacs. And zsh (which you appear to be using) doesn't have a way to disable this message. Neither does bash, nor I think any other common shell.

Your attempts with `stty susp undef` and `set +m` cannot possibly help because they have no impact on this message. All they can do is prevent suspension from working properly.

A way not to have this message is to invoke a single Emacs process. Typically, you do this by [starting Emacs as a daemon with your session](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsAsDaemon). Then, to open Emacs in a terminal, run `emacsclient -t` (you can of course make a shell alias for it). This opens a frame of the running Emacs instance in the current terminal. To go back to the shell, use `C-x C-c`, which closes the current frame (but doesn't kill Emacs since it was started as a daemon). To open Emacs again, run `emacsclient -t` again.

Comment: Using only `emacsclient -t` opens a *scratch* file. Please see: (https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/59669/18414). Main goal of asking this question is when I close emacs using `C-x C-c` to get back to shell, I was trying to find a way to open the latest buffer using `emacsclient -t` afterwards (which is the actual behavior of `suspend-emacs` and than do `fg` to get back to latest buffer - console location), is it possible to achieve it?