# How emacsclient automatically startup with the most recent file?

Tags: emacsclient, recentf

With the help of `recentf` I am able to open recently open files from its `buffer list`. As an example when I execute `icicle-buffer`, I can see the *buffer list*.

I was wondering can I do this operation automatically where the most recent file (buffer) will be open with the help of a function instead of manually selecting.

*Basically my main goal is:* when I open `emacsclient` I want to start it with the most recently file, which is I belive the first index file on the *buffer list*.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, so far. Is it really about Icicles and/or Helm, or is it just about how to have `emacslient` automatically start up with the most recent file? If the former, add tags `icicles` and/or `helm`, and say how they are related to the emacsclient part. If the latter, remove the Icicles and Helm part.

Comment: It is not related to `Icicles and/or Helm`. Yes just about: how emacsclient automatically startup with the most recent file and I removed `Icicles and Helm` part

Comment: Thanks!    ________

Comment: `emacsclient -e '(recentf-open-most-recent-file 1)'` perhaps?

Comment: @NickD: this keeps return `#<buffer recentf>` on my end, i think it keeps opening a buffer called recentf

Comment: I tried `recentf-open-most-recent-file-3` I returns the buffer name but does not open it

Comment: `C-h f recentf-open-most-recent-file` says: "Open the Nth most recent file."  Works fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

In your .emacs file add the following

(desktop-save-mode 1)

Emacs will open back up exactly like it was sans any buffers not tied to files

Comment: I already have it but I believe it does something else

Comment: You don't have it or you don't have it right because I have that and Emacs always comes right back up with the same set of files and remembers where I was. If you are working with buffers that aren't tied to files, then no, nothing will work as those do not get saved so there is nothing to restore.

Comment: `(desktop-save-mode 1)` does not open the most recent file

Comment: It does for me on 3 different machines. Two of them running Ubuntu 20.04 and one running KDE Neon. It even worked in Windows 10 running in a VM.

Comment: certainly, it doesn't when starting from emacsclient.